# Inequalities for the norms of the fractional Fourier transform

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-transform, young-inequality

## Introduction and definitions

When considering the norms of a function $f(x)$ and its Fourier transform, $\tilde{f}$,
\begin{equation}
\tilde{f}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-iyx}f(x) \,,
\end{equation}
defined according to
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_p = \left(\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\,,
\end{equation}
the following inequality holds
\begin{equation}
\|\tilde f\|_q \leq k(p,q) \|f\|_p  \,,
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1 \,, \quad q\geq 2 \,.
\end{equation}

The optimal constant for $k(p,q)$ was calculated by Beckner [1] (as well as others) and is equal to:
\begin{equation}
k(p,q) = \left(\frac{2\pi}{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{2q}} \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2p}}\,. 
\end{equation}

## The question

Now, instead of considering the Fourier transform, consider the [fractional Fourier transform](http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/MONeill/Math%20138/papers138/Beckner.pdf) for some angle $2\pi/n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}\,, n\geq 3$. Then denoting by 
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}^{(j)}=\mathcal{F}\ldots \mathcal{F} [f] \,, 1\leq j \leq n-1 
\end{equation}
the result of applying the fractional Fourier transform to $f$ $j$ times, one has the modified Beckner inequality
\begin{equation}
\|\hat f ^{(j)} \|_q \leq c(p,q) \|\hat f ^{(j-1)}\|_p  \,,
\end{equation}
again with
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1 \,, \quad q\geq 2 \,.
\end{equation}

Similarly to the case of the Fourier transform, the optimal constant can be calculated and is found to be equal to:
\begin{equation}
c(p,q) = d(p) \, k(p,q) \,, 
\end{equation}
and where $d(p)$ is a factor that essentially depends on the angle $2\pi/n$. (see e.g. [2] or [3], behind paywall)

I am wondering if there exists an inequality for the norms of all the $\hat{f}^{(j)}$'s (or at least more than two) at the same time, which does not trivially follows by combining the Beckner-type ones. For example, with $n=3$, is there some inequality of the form
\begin{equation}
a(p,q,r)\| \hat{f}^{(2)}\|_p + b(p,q,r)\|\hat{f}^{(1)}\|_q + c(p,q,r)\|f\|_r \geq 0 \,,
\end{equation}
for certain $a,b,c$ and potentially some constraints on the $p,q,r$?

Any relevant results and references would be highly appreciated.

## References

[1]  [W. Beckner, Annals of Mathematics, **102**, 159-182 (1975)](http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/MONeill/Math%20138/papers138/Beckner.pdf)

[2] [E.H. Lieb, Inventions Math., **102**,179-208 (1990)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01233426)

[3] [X.Guanlei, W.Xiaotong, X.Xiaogang, IET Signal Process 3, 392–402 (2009)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5227801/)